# Readonly alias in Bash

Tags: bash, function, alias, readonly

In Bash I can mark functions as readonly doing something like this

> `declare -r -f functionName`

Is there any way to do the same thing with alias names? I mean: once an alias is set I don't want it to be assigned again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No; aliases use a separate namespace.  You are really better off using functions instead of aliases (not just for this reason).

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge I believe no.

**Reason for judgement**:

You can always invoke the pure command by appending a `\` (backslah). e.g. if you would aliased ls to `ls -lrt`, you can always invoke to non-aliased version of ls by writing `\ls`. So, in a way, alias is not permanent/unmodifiable in any sense.